# Seeking ideas on how best to splice+move breakers from one panel to adjacent panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, junction-box, splicing

[image]
As the title says, I need to move (per my new load calcs after changes were made) three of the bottom breakers on the left panel, over to the right panel. However, the wires do not have enough slack to move them over. Even though it may not seem like it at first glance, the panel on the right has room to move them while staying within the 80% rule on both panels. The amp loads on the double pole breakers on the right are much smaller than the ones on the left. Likewise, the loads on the single poles are minimal as well.

The wires that need to be moved are all 8/2. The only thing I can think of that would work is mounting the junction box(s) to the outside of those middle studs. There is less than 4-6" of space between the spray foam and the back of the studs. Is there any other solution I am overlooking? Also, is there anything that would be against code in my plan? If everything is otherwise ok per code, would you recommend one very large junction box (I like to give myself lots of extra room when splicing 6-8awg) or smaller, individual junction boxes for each separate run? My only concern is that aesthetically, the large junction boxes mounted to the outside of the middle studs would look a little ridiculous, but I'm not sure what the alternative is. This isn't to say the wiring above doesn't look ridiculous, but here I am.

P.S. Yes, my friend who originally did all those 10/2 on the left and right panels over 2 years ago should have had them come in at 90 degrees. The inspector noted as much but otherwise said it was fine. I had done all the terminations and path through the attic, and left it up to him to finish the runs to the panel. If I had it to do over, I would have finished it myself.

Comment: The panel itself can be used as a junction box if there is space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your panels also count as large junction boxes.  What I would do there is run a short run of EMT or RMC between the two panels.  The panels appear to be the same brand and size so it is likely the knockouts will face each other, saving you any metal work.  The only tricky part will be drilling through the stud, but a right-angle drill should fit in there.  Honestly, while you're in there, I'd do 2 or 3 runs between the panels if I could, allowing space for further moves.

As long as you stay within box fill rules for your panel (extremely unlikely you could ever hit that limit) and conduit fill for your pipe, you are good.

Then, connect #8 THWN jumpers from the ends of your 8/2 cables in the old panel to the new breakers in the new panel.  You don't need to move grounds, just hot and neutral (if there are any neutrals).

I like to use sharpie on leftover cuttings of NM cable insulation to group the pairs (or triplets or whatever) on both sides to make future troubleshooting easier.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow it didn't occur to me to use the panels as junction boxes. There is open space behind the horizontal studs, but it will indeed be a little tricky to work my hands in those tight spaces; I'm sure I will figure it out though. Thanks again for the suggestion!

Comment: If you can't run behind: Dismount one panel, drill hole through stud lined up with a knockout, thread EMT through that hole, remount panel and secure EMT to both boxes.